# Element position affected by overflow:hidden

Tags: css, overflow

I am experiencing an issue which (at least to me) seems very weird. It is a menu, which, if you hover over a tab, expands its height and shows the menu items. The tab has the property overflow:hidden, so that the items are only shown when you hover on the tab.
Now, what's really strange, when you hover over the tab and it expands, the other tab's bottom seems to follow the bottom of the first - so that the other tab moves downward as the first expands. And this behavior disappears if I remove overflow:hidden!
Now, I did some position:absolute trickery here, but I double checked that the relevant parts are positioned relatively. I am out of ideas as to what may cause this, though.

---

Here is a very minimal test case:

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-tab">Hover here!</div>
    <div class="menu-tab">Or here!</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu {  /* issue disappears without this */
    height: 15pt;
}

.menu-tab {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;  /* required for animation, not affecting behavior */
    overflow: hidden;  /* this one! */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.menu-tab:hover {
    height: 500%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2abofkLp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `vertical-align` property on the tab:

```css
#menu {
  /* issue disappears without this */
  height: 15pt;
}

.menu-tab {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* add this */
  height: 100%;
  /* required for animation, not affecting behavior */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* this one! */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.menu-tab:hover {
  height: 500%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu-tab">Hover here!</div>
  <div class="menu-tab">Or here!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `vertical-align:top;` so that the `inline-block` elements remain aligned.

```css
#menu {
  /* issue disappears without this */
  height: 15pt;
}

.menu-tab {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* THIS */
  height: 100%;
  /* required for animation, not affecting behavior */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* this one! */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.menu-tab:hover {
  height: 500%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu-tab">Hover here!</div>
  <div class="menu-tab">Or here!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for accepting ovokuro's answer, they are exactly similar, but his was a tad earlier. Also, still, why does overflow:hidden cause this?